# Localized Content in Amplience Dynamic Content

Tags: amplience-dynamic-content

What is the best approach to creating and organizing localized content in Amplience Dynamic Content.  Should it be done through a content type (json) or rendering (html, css, .js) or other methods (web hook integrations)

Answer (score 1):

I use multiple repositories one for each language. I put my localised content in each one then create slot type with JSON schema that creates an array of content links that you can point at each local variant.  Alternatively you can have an array of content types with a field defined as a locale enumeration and a content link.
e.g.

**Slot**

--localized content array

----local:en

----content:link to content in en repository

----local:es

----content:link to content in es repository

----local:fr

----content:link to content in fr repository

Example localized slot content type
https://github.com/zestrax/dynamic-content-samples/blob/Development/content-types/slot/localized-slot.json

Use the render service to filter the graph on request e.g.

Create a partial for each country en.HBS which loops through the slot array and return the content matching its locale

you would create a handlebars partial ‘en.hendlebars’  like this to filter the local content in a slot for language 'en'.

```
{{#each content-list}}
    {{#compare locale "==" "en"}}
        {{!-- call a partial for to render the locale content --}}
        {{>mapping this.content.content-type}}
    {{/compare}}
{{/each}}
```